# Suppose that an urn contains 6 red and 3 green balls. Two are drawn randomly and without replacement.

Tags: probability

> The sample space is $S = \{(g_1, g_2),(g_1, r_2),(r_1, g_2),(r_1, r_2)\}$.
>
> (a) Fine $\Pr(E_i)$ for every singleton event $E_i ⊂ S$.
>
> (b) Let $X$ denote the number of red balls. Find the probability function of $X$.
>
> (c) Find the cumulative <s>density</s> distribution function of $X$.
>
> (d) Find the expected value of $X$.

I got the probabilities for each sample space. $\Pr\{({\tt G,G})\} = 1/12$.   Both $\Pr\{({\tt G,R})\}$ and $\Pr\{({\tt R,G})\} = 1/4$.   $\Pr\{({\tt R,R})\} = 5/12$.   I'm not sure if they're right and I have no idea how to continue from here to solve b,c, and d.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I got the probabilities for each sample space. Pr(GG) = 1/12. Pr(GR) and Pr(RG) = 1/4. Pr(RR) = 5/12. I'm not sure if they're right and I have no idea how to continue from here to solve b,c, and d.

Comment: Your answers to part (a) are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) that can take on the values $0$, $1$, and $2$.  The probability that $X=0$ is the same as the probability of the event $(G_1,G_2)$ (which you have correctly calculated as $1/12$).  You should see that the probability that $X=1$ is the same as the probability of either event $(G_1,R_2)$ or event $(R_1,G_2)$ happening.  Since these two events are disjoint, the probability of their union is the sum of their probabilities.  The probability that $X=2$ is the same as the probability of the event $(R_1,R_2)$.  Can you answer the remaining questions now?

Comment: I think so. The cumulative sum will be F(0) = X=0. F(1) = (X=0)+(x=1). F(2) = (X=0)+(x=1)+(X=2). And expected value is (0*X=0) + (1*X=1) + (2*X=2). Is that correct? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: More precisely, $F(0)=P(X=0)$, $F(1)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)$, and $F(2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$.  Also, $E[X]=0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)$.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I got the probabilities for each sample space. $\Pr\{({\tt G,G})\} = 1/12$.   Both $\Pr\{({\tt G,R})\}$ and $\Pr\{({\tt R,G})\} = 1/4$.   $\Pr\{({\tt R,R})\} = 5/12$.   I'm not sure if they're right and I have no idea how to continue from here to solve b,c, and d.

They are correct.   $\checkmark$

For (b) use these to determine $\mathsf P(X=x)$ for $x\in\{0,1,2\}$

$$\mathsf P(X=x) =\begin{cases} \Pr\{({\tt G,G})\} & : x=0 \\ ? & : x=1 \\ ? & : x=2 \\ 0 & : \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

For (c) use those to determine $\mathsf P(X\leq x)$.

$$\mathsf P(X=x) =\begin{cases} 0 & : x<0 \\ ? & : 0\leq x< 1 \\ ? & : 1\leq x < 2 \\ 1 & : 2 \leq x\end{cases}$$

For (d) use $\mathsf E(X) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^2 x~\mathsf P(X=x)$

$$\mathsf E(X) = \mathsf P(X=1) + 2\mathsf P(X=2)$$